# Silverligth Application Using Ria Service without .web project

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria

Is it possible to build a SL application with RIA class library without the .web project.
I mean the Business will be hosted on the RIA class library, do I still need the first generated .web for my SL project?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create them separately - the key bit is the 'WCF RIA Services Link' which you'll set on your Silverlight project once your RIA web app is around for it to use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707372(VS.91).aspx

Comment: I know you can create them seperatly, what I mean in my question, do I still need the .web project or I can delete it.

Comment: if your Silverlight project no longer points to it via its WCF RIA Services link, then yes, you can delete away. :)